# shellscript内でsourceコマンドが使えない

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, shellscript, raspbian

## やりたいこと

shellscriptの中でsourceコマンドを使いraspiの中にpython3系の仮想環境を起動しpythonスクリプトを動かしたい

## 疑問点

sourceとshellscript(bash)の関係性として
・bashは閉じられた環境で動き
・sourceは開いた環境で動く
っていうのはなんとなく分かり、shoptコマンドでエイリアスを展開するようにしてみたんですが
shoptコマンドも動いてくれませんでした。。。

どうすればshellscriptでsourceコマンドが動くのでしょうか？

#### start.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s expand_aliases
source bin/activate

echo "start"
echo python ${実行したいpythonファイル}
echo "end"
exit 0
```

#### 結果

```
$ sh -x start.sh
+ shopt
start.sh: 3: start.sh: shopt: not found
+ /bin/shopt -s expand_aliases
start.sh: 5: start.sh: /bin/shopt: not found
+ /bin/source /data/harvest/bin/activate
start.sh: 6: start.sh: /bin/source: not found
～後略～
```

Comment: `bash start.sh` とするか、`start.sh` に実行パーミッションを付けて(`chmod u+x start.sh`)、`./start.sh` としてみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: 上記、ご提示していただいた２つの手順どちらからでも実施できました！ありがとうございます。`sh ~`で勝手にbashになると僕が思い込んでいたのが原因ですね。。。失礼いたしました。

Comment: @cossy お疲れさまでした！　スタック・オーバーフローでは自己回答ができるので、質問に追記するのではなく、回答として投稿してみてください。どうぞよろしくお願いいたします<(_ _)>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@metropolisさん
ありがとうございました。
@nekketsuuさん
失礼いたしました、行ったことを回答に移動いたしました。

## 解決策

chmodで実行権限つけるか
`bash start.sh`で起動する

## 原因

私のshコマンドに対する理解不足

Comment: デフォルトの`shell`が何か解りませんが、`bash`で必ず実行される様にするためには、そのスクリプトを`chmod u+x [実行したいシェルスクリプト名]`として、実行パーミッションを与え、`/usr/local/bin`に置くか、シェルスクリプトのあるディレクトリーで./[シェルスクリプト名]とすると、1行目の`#! /bin/bash`で実行してくれます。お試し下さい